# How do you convert a list of lists to a sequence of lists?

Tags: racket

If you have a list `'((a b) (c d) (e f))`, how would you convert it to `'(a b) '(c d) '(e f)` so that you can put any appropriate function in front of it such as `(append '(a b) '(c d) '(e f))`, or syntax macros? Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29), which does this in general.

```
(apply append '((a b) (c d) (e f))) ; '(a b c d e f)
(apply + '(1 2 3))                  ; 6
```

Comment: Hmm I have tried apply, however it does not seem to work with macro patterns such as `myMacro arg1 arg2 arg3`. I have tried `apply myMacro '((a b) (c d) (e f))`.

Comment: I am not familiar with macros. Someone else can probably provide a better answer that deals with macros.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your attempt though.